# Alternatives to String.Compare for performance

Tags: string, optimization, c#-4.0

I've used a profiler on my C# application and realised that String.Compare() is taking a lot of time overall: 43% of overall time with 124M hits

I'm comparing relatively small string: from 4 to 50 chars. 
What would you recommend to replace it with in terms of performance??

**UPD:** I only need to decide if 2 strings are the same or not. Strings can be zero or "". No cultural aspect or any other aspect to it. Most of the time it'll be "4578D" compared to "1235E" or similar.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: This depends on your use case! Do you want to make culture aware comparisons or not?

Comment: I only care if 2 strings are equal. I'll put update. Thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on what sort of comparison you want to make. If you only care about equality, then use one of the `Equals` overloads - for example, it's quicker to find that two strings have different lengths than to compare their contents.

If you're happy with an ordinal comparison, explicitly specify that:

```
int result = string.CompareOrdinal(x, y);
```

An ordinal comparison can be *much* faster than a culture-sensitive one.

Of course, that assumes that an ordinal comparison gives you the result you want - correctness is usually more important than performance (although not always).

EDIT: Okay, so you *only* want to test for equality. I'd just use the `==` operator, which uses an ordinal equality comparison.

Comment: All I care about if 2 strings are the same or not. I'll give it a go. Thanks Jon! Celebrity in my topic - flattered -)

Comment: @trailmax: In that case you definitely shouldn't be using `Compare` to start with. As edited, just use `==`.

Comment: I had == in the first version, then changed to Compare() because one of the strings came as null. And was to lazy to put comparison for null first.

Comment: @trailmax: So what do you want to happen if one of the strings is null? Do you *want* a NullReferenceException? You could always explicitly call Equals instead: `x.Equals(y)`.

Comment: In my case null != "a" and null == null and ""=="". I don't want NullReferenceException in any cases.

Comment: @trailmax: Just using `==` will be fine then. You won't get any NullReferenceExceptions.

Comment: Thanks! I surely will try this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use different ways of comparing strings.

```
String.Compare(str1, str2, StringComparison.CurrentCulture) // default
String,Compare(str1, str2, StringComparison.Ordinal) // fastest
```

Making an ordinal comparison can be something like twice as fast as a culture dependant comparison.

If you make a comparison for equality, and the strings doesn't contain any culture depenant characters, you can very well use ordinal comparison.